# Re-entering Singapore after a six-day visit stamp

Tags: visas, singapore

I'm a Filipino national. I had a work permit, and after my visa expired in February 2018 my boyfriend and I decided to go to Batam, Indonesia, and come back to Singapore after 3 days. Luckily I got a 30-day stamp.

I went back home in March 2018,and after 2 months I tried to enter Singapore again with my mom and kids. Luckily I got 30 days again. My mom and my children went back to the Philippines after 3 days, but I stayed in Singapore for the remainder of my 30 days.

After that my boyfriend asked me to go to Genting, Malaysia, because he had 2 days off and he wanted to relax. When we tried to enter Singapore again, I was brought to the office and asked some questions. After that they gave me 6 days only. I went back to the Philippines on July 5.

Having a "6-day visit" stamp from Singapore immigration, if I want to visit Singapore again, will it be hard for me? How long do I need to wait?

Comment: what is your citizenship? How long between visits? Generally "you visited here before and left" is not a problem, but it can be if the visits are so close together that it's really just one long visit. Please edit your question to add details.

Comment: But i need more answer on how long i need to wait to visit again my bf .  He has to time to go home here anf im the only free dat can visit him there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You've clearly landed on the radar of Singapore Immigration for visa running**.  There is no automatic reset period, and further attempts to visit Singapore visa-free without strong business reasons are likely to be treated with deep suspicion.

If possible, I strongly recommend you apply for a **Long-Term Social Visit Pass**, which will let you legally stay in Singapore beyond 30 days.  However, depending on your boyfriend's Singapore residence/visa status, this may be impossible, in which case I would advise that he come visit you in the Philippines instead.  Marriage may also be an option, although this too depends on his residence status.

Comment: Hi Jpatokal he is Filipino national also and an S pass holder only

Comment: In that case I'm not aware of any options for you.  Sorry.